# CDF of quotient of RVs?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

What would be density function for the ratio of X/Y, for both uniform and exponential distributions?

For the first one, I think that $P(C⩽c)=P(B⩾A/c)=E[e^{-A/c}]$ but unsure what that is. I am stuck on the second.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Questions like "Here is the task. Solve it for me!" are poorly received on this site. Therefore try to improve your question with an [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3005541/edit). Improving could consist of providing some context concerning your task or by adding what you have tried so far and where did you struggle :)

Comment: Why would $\mathsf P(B\geqslant A/c)=\mathsf E(e^{-1X/z})$ ?  Where did the $X$ and $z$ come from?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hint:

- Can you solve the problem if $B$ was a constant, and not a random variable?
- How can you combine the above and the law of total probability to get your answer?

[image: Law of total probability]

Image sourced from [here](https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter5/5_2_3_conditioning_independence.php)

Answer (score 0):

> For the first one, I think that $P(C⩽c)=P(B⩾A/c)=E[e^{-1X/z}]$ but unsure what that is.

When did random variable $X$ and constant $z$ enter into the discussion?

However, it is that: $$\begin{align}\mathsf P(C\leqslant c)&=\mathsf P(B\geqslant A/c)\\&=\mathsf E(\mathsf P(B\geqslant A/c\mid A))\\&=\mathsf E(e^{-A/c})\end{align}$$

The rest is just evaluating the expectation: $\mathsf E(g(A))=\int_\Bbb R f_A(a)~g(a)~\mathsf d a$ $$\mathsf E(e^{-A/c})=\int_0^\infty e^{-a}~e^{-a/c}~\mathsf d a$$

> I am stuck on the second.

Second verse, much the same as the first.

Hint: it is a peicewise function partitioned on the magnitude of $c$.   Consider the cases $0<c< 1$ and $1\leqslant c$

Comment: So to be clear for the first one: (e^−A/c) is the CDF and then would the pdf just be e^(-a)*e^(-a/c)?

Comment: Also for the second, would you be able to help with what the partitions are?

Comment: $\mathsf P(C\leqslant c)=\mathsf E(e^{-A/c})$ is the CDF of $C$.  The pdf of $C$ is the derivative of that *with respect to* $c$.   (Also, I clued you in on what the partitions should be.  Consider those cases.)

Comment: I am saying that if E(e^-A/c) is the CDF -- and that is the integral of some function f(a) -- can't I just say that f(a) (ie: the thing being integrated) is the PDF?

Comment: No, since the integral is **not** *with respect to* $c$.